# How to get an editable ComboBox to respond to ENTER

Tags: event-handling, javafx, keyevent, enter

This code is what I want to do. While typing in an editable ComboBox I want to release ENTER and handle that enter event. However, I cannot get the application to respond, a message was not printed. I wrote basically the same code for a text box and it worked fine, a message was printed. I also wrote the handler for any KeyReleased event for a ComboBox and that worked fine also, a message was printed. The trouble is the enter key. Why does this code not do what I want in an editable ComboBox?

```
@FXML
ComboBox comboBox;

public class ScreenController implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(...) {
        ...
        comboBox.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getCode == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    System.out.println("ENTER was released");
            }
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's look to be a JavaFX bug. setOnKeyPressed doesn't work to. look at this
[javafx jira](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-29183)

Answer (score 2):

I was suffering from the same bug/feature. Luckily I found [this posting](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2013/08/15/java-fx-2-editable-combobox-does-not-detect-esc-enter-space-key/)
The solution is not to register your handler via `comboBox.setOnKeyReleased()`. instead, use EventFilter:

```
comboBox.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ke.getCode == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                System.out.println("ENTER was released");
            }
        }
 });
```

This actually works as expected.